# How to set up a complex minecraft command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am a total noob at commands. I can do really simple ones like fill-replace stone to air in a specific area, but I can't figure out how to set up the code for things which require more complex logic or combined arguments. At the moment I'm trying to set up a command block to pick a random jungle wood stair block and replace it with an acacia wood stair and keep doing this until I shut it down, to try and give the roof on my large scale building a weathered look. Can somebody please explain how to code that and why all the parts are set up the way they are?

Comment: Aare you asking how to code in general or for this one machine, with explained parts?

Comment: Does it have to be random? You could just use the command `/fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> acacia_stairs 0 replace jungle_stairs` to do it instantly.

Comment: How to code in general, but since it's overwhelming to try and learn it all at once, I figured it would be simpler to use one specific action to break down and explain how the logic and individual parts work together.

Comment: Are you trying to make it look like its getting more rotten over time?

Comment: If it were left running, yes. I would only leave it going until I was satisfied with the look at a given point. I'm not sure exactly what percentage I want of each color, so I figured something that just keeps going a little at a time would give me a bit of leeway to see what looks best.

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't vanilla, I would use WorldEdit for this. Much simpler.

Just select the area with the WorldEdit wand then do:

```
//replace junglestair:DATAVALUE 10%acaciastair:DATAVALUE,90%junglestair:DATAVALUE
```

which will replace 10% of your jungle stairs with acacia stairs. You'll have to do the command once for each stair orientation though. (Replace "DATAVALUE" with the proper number for each orientation)

You'll need the clientside mod or the plugin (on a bukkit/spigot server) to do this though.

Answer (score -1):

Depends, you could have a command block for each jungle stair and then have a `setblock` command for it and then just have a `RandomRedstoneAlternator` on it (RRA), but that also requires a lot of redstone skill and gets very complex if you have a large roof on your house. Send me a screenshot of the roof and I possibly will be able to send you a schematic of how you could do it.

Comment: I haven't built the roof yet, as I haven't figured out whether I need to manually do the detailing or can just get the basic shape down and have a bunch of command blocks modify it. I'm doing it at a 4:1 scale or possibly larger, so if I end up having to do it manually, I'd rather just build in the details as I go. If it helps give you an idea of what it will look like, my intent is to make a replica of the house from "Secondhand Lions".

Comment: unfortunately i have not watched that movie so i do not know what you mean. again you will have to send me a schematic for me to be able to help you sorry. ~Scratchndent